# Excel change selected cells color based on their current color

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to change the color of selected cells, but not all, just the ones that have certain color.

```
Sub mudacor()
    If Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then
        Else

        With Selection.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 15987699
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End If
    
End Sub
```

I've been playing around with the code and this changes the entire selection!
the objective is to change every cell in white to gray but leaving the cells with no color unchanged! (all cells in the selection with or without data in them)

Sub mudacor()

```
If Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 2 Then
    
    With Selection.Interior
        .Color = 15987699
    End With

End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Your `If` statement seems to be opposite to what you want to do.

Comment: Agree with Tom. What happens if you take out that `Else`, is that what you were aiming for?

Comment: Sorry, I had it wrong, I want to change color of the cells with color leaving the cells without color as they are!

Comment: What is the result of this code on your cells (please edit that into your question)?

Answer (score 0):

Try `If Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone Then` (without your trailing `Else`).

See: Microsoft's [`XlColorIndex` docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlcolorindex).